# Peer to Peer (P2P) connection between 2 windows phone 8 device

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, p2p

What i am trying to do is to set up a service desk kind app (VOIP style). where a user will initiate a call and there will be another person on the other line. Is this possible without some kind of server?

Comment: And how would devices discover each other?

Comment: Is it possible to use just the IP Address for locating the other device?

Comment: I guess most devices will operate behind NAT thus you will have neither their IPs nor possibility to directly connect to them.

Comment: I see, Do you have any suggestions or possible solutions to this? I have already built the streaming part of the app the problem i have is sending it to the other side.

Comment: Peer discovery and connectivity is the largest problem in p2p . Servers are needed. Study how Skype solves this problem.